# Why is Core Module missing from angular docs?

Tags: angular

I am about to design the architecture of an angular application so am reading about the best practices for managing modules and there is a so called Core Module in every post and thread but it is missing from the latest angular documentation and I don't know why. Is it still reasonable to create one, or has it loss it's purpose?

Comment: Do you find the answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreModule style guide has been removed since Angular 7, it has been replaced by the `providedIn` attribute in the `@Injectable` decorator. I think the main purpose of that change is to bring more flexibility to Angular modules and to make them more independant.

However, this pattern is still available in my opinion if you want to have global third party libraries included in the whole application (like flex layout or material modules, etc...).

PS: I have written an article about CoreModule / SharedModule: https://medium.com/@benmohamehdi/angular-best-practices-coremodule-vs-sharedmodule-25f6721aa2ef

PS2: You still have this style guide documented in version 6: https://v6.angular.io/guide/styleguide#core-feature-module

Answer (score 0):

I am going to explain you a bit about all the modules. There is a specific purpose of each module `(Core, Shared etc..)`.

> Your question is about the **`Core Module`** but I will cover all related to **`Architecture`**.

So suppose of an application which has the following modules:

1. App Module
2. Core Module
3. Shared Module
4. User Module `(This is called feature module)`
5. Admin Module `(This is called feature module)`

**Let's describe it:**

**App Module**

In this module, you have to import the modules/packages which you will use throughout your system. Like: `CommonModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule` etc. And you don't need to export these modules as it will be available in whole application once it is imported in App Module.

---

**Core Module**

In this module, you have to make components which will be used in almost every page of the system. Like: `HeaderComponent, FooterCompoennt, AuthGaurds` etc. And these components should be exported so that it will be available in other modules.

---

**Shared Module**

In this module, you have to make the `Services, Components, Pipes, and Directives` which will be used in more than one component. Like: `AlertDialogBox, APIService,` etc.

---

**User Module**

This is a featured module. It will have the components specific to a User Module. Here you can import `Shared Module` so that you can use `AlertDialogBox and all`.

---

**Admin Module**

This is a featured module. It will have the components specific to a User Module. Here you can import `Shared Module` so that you can use `AlertDialogBox and all`.

---